# URL is altered after parsing with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

```
str = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><url>https://somehost?p1=v1&p2=v2</url>"
=> "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><url>https://somehost?p1=v1&p2=v2</url>"

x = Nokogiri::XML(str)
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x3fcaa893b900 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fcaa893b644 name="url" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fcaa893b48c "https://somehost?p1=v1=v2">]>]>
```

Why is '&p2' removed? after parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in an XML/HTML context `&` has special meaning. You *must* escape it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><url>https://somehost?p1=v1&amp;p2=v2</url>
```

It's parsing that as an entity `&p2`, which it isn't a valid entity, so it gets deleted, leaving you with `p1=v1=p2`

Comment: I'm sure that's a correct explanation, though in theory a W3C-conformant XML parser is not allowed to attempt recovery from syntax errors in this way, it should report an error and stop.

Comment: @MichaelKay If you've got a case here, write up a bug report.

Comment: If you think I'm going to install a piece of software that I've never used, familiarise myself with it, and run a test just so that I can submit a bug report, then you've got an odd idea about my priorities in life. In any case, I've no idea if it's a bug. It might be an intentional and documented non-conformance. There's no law requiring W3C conformance, after all.

Comment: Nokogiri is somewhat like a puppy in that it'll try to return something useful, which is good when trying to do lots of batch processing. The downside to that is the HTML or XML can be mangled as it tries to recover from bad input. The `errors` method helps, which when used on the OPs document tells us there's a problem: `# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 1:69: FATAL: EntityRef: expecting ';'>]`, in other words it thought the `&p2` was an entity and couldn't do anything with it. The programmer has to take advantage of this and react accordingly. If `errors` returns an empty list it's OK.